# Netstream video chat client freezes and crashes after time

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, netstream

So I built a videochat client that uses the adobe stratus protocol. Its very simple and just connects two users. However, after about a minute of video chatting the clients freeze and the browser crashes.

Any idea what might have caused this? Is there some sort of cache that I need to clear every so often or a possible memory leak? I am not sure where to start. Thanks!

I tried to debug it, but when it freezes nothing is outputted.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you been checking out what Tom Krcha is doing at FlashRealTime? http://flashrealtime.com/tuts/p2p-in-flash.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i saw a similar problem [there](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2796970) so you may try [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2423240#2423240) as mentioned in that thread.

cheers !..